# How to debug RCP plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

Is it possible to debug an RCP Plugin in Eclipse. I have to debug an RCP plugin which is already into production. Can you please help me out how to do it in Eclipse.

Comment: Have you tried running the app using -Xdebug ? See http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-setup-remote-debugging-in.html

Comment: Do you have the Eclipse projects so that you can use Eclipse debug?

Answer (score 0):

You can debug an Eclipse application in production as any other Java application. You have to add parameters to run the application and create a specific run configuration in Eclipse. See [this post](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t53459.html) (note I have not gone through the steps, I just checked it seemed to contain what I usually do).